# Unable to Authenticate in Swagger

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, swagger

Hi I have developed web application in .net core. I registered two application in azure ad. One for my web api and one for my swagger. As per http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2018/08/configure-swagger-to-authenticate-against-azure-ad/  We need to add api access in swagger to communicate with web api. But whenever I try to add permission in azure portal I dont see my web api app. I am not sure I do not see my web app to give api access. Next Whenever I click on authorize in swagger I get error message The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Below is error screen shot.

Below is code.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
                {
                    Type = "oauth2",
                    Flow = "implicit",
                    AuthorizationUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/8b95-448d-b259-98a44d112f7c/oauth2/authorize",
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                       { "openid", "Sign In Permissions" },
                       { "profile", "User Profile Permissions" } },
                    TokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/98a44d112f7c/oauth2/token"
                });
            });
```

In configure,

```
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.OAuthClientId(Configuration["Swagger:ClientId"]);
                c.OAuthClientSecret(Configuration["Swagger:ClientSecret"]);
                c.OAuthRealm(Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"]);
                c.OAuthAppName("My API V1");
                c.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
                c.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(new { resource = Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"] });
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
```

May I know how can I fix the above issue? Can someone help me to find this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using the v1 endpoint and not specifying the resource. You can either a) specify the resource parameter (the client id/ app id URI of your API) or b) use the v2 endpoint with a scope specifying a scope on your API. Don't use openid and profile, those are for id tokens, you need an access token.

Comment: Hi Junnas thanks for your answer. I have added my swagger code. Can you help me to add exact code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that is different in one of my apps is that we define the additional query parameters with a dictionary:

```
options.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["resource"] = _configuration["SwaggerUi:ApiResourceUri"]
});
```

But that's probably not the reason for the issue.
You need to find the Swagger app registration in Azure AD, identified by the client id you have in `Configuration["Swagger:ClientId"]`.
There you need to go to API permissions, and add all of the delegated permissions defined by your API.

If you haven't defined any scopes, find the app registration for your API and open the Expose an API tab.
Guide for adding scopes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#exposing-delegated-permissions-scopes

Also, technically you don't need to specify scopes, since you are using the v1 endpoint.

Comment: Thanks I am able to add app. I added scope after that I was able to add client application. Now I am able to authorize I am getting 401 error. I have added screen shot above.

Comment: Did you require the scope on the swagger app and grant it?

Comment: Also I inspected in network tab. www-authenticate: Bearer is coming without token. May I know what would be the issue?

Comment: No i dont need scope. But Without scope I am not able to add client app

Comment: My auth url is  AuthorizationUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/someid/oauth2/authorize", Is this correct?

Comment: As per your  above comment I have   c.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(new { resource = Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"] }); Do i need to add swagger client id here?

Comment: Yeah those look okay. But your swagger app in Azure AD should require that scope to the API.

Comment: So in swagger app also i should add same scope?

Comment: In the API permissions tab, you need to add the API scope. It defines that swagger requires that access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199443/discussion-between-niranjan-and-juunas).